# How to perform the B-spline interpolation in Julia?

Tags: julia, interpolation, spline

I want to interpolate the following 2x1 matrix (example for clarity of question):

```
x=collect(300:50:900)
y=rand(13)
```

the query points 'xq' are:

```
xq=collect(290:4:910)
```

in this case, how can I get the query point of y 'yq'?

I tried some interpolation methods (such as interpolations and Diercks..), but nothing worked (or I did wrong way..). I'm so confused. please share your know-how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What have you tried? What did not work?

Before looking at the interpolation, note that you usually don't have to use `collect` - it creates unnecessary arrays and thereby allocations and negates the benefits of working with the lightweight `StepRange` type created by an expression like `300:50:900`.

Here's an example with [`BSplineKit`](https://jipolanco.github.io/BSplineKit.jl/) following the first example in the docs:

```
julia> using BSplineKit

julia> x = 300:50:900; y = rand(length(x));

julia> itp = interpolate(x, y, BSplineOrder(4))
SplineInterpolation containing the 13-element Spline{Float64}:
 basis: 13-element BSplineBasis of order 4, domain [300.0, 900.0]
 order: 4
 knots: [300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 300.0, 400.0, 450.0, 500.0, 550.0, 600.0, 650.0, 700.0, 750.0, 800.0, 900.0, 900.0, 900.0, 900.0]
 coefficients: [0.164315, 0.399353, 0.866037, 0.325909, 1.16957, 0.990489, 0.74577, 0.882066, 0.698501, 0.684713, 1.27336, -0.49067, 0.985016]
 interpolation points: 300:50:900


julia> itp.(290:4:910)
156-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
 0.1785050188621375
 0.8996276319427731
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

The only thing I've changed from the docs is to broadcast the `itp` function over the range of query points.

Here's what the result looks like:

[image]